# I am trying to convert an outside link and redirect

Tags: redirect, hyperlink

I have another site (to sent packadge) and this site creates a link (for a label)

The link is like https://example.com/text1/tekst2/123456789

I can't modify this link.

But I like the link to be https://example.com/anothertext/123456789.

Can I post this to my own site, convert it and redirect?

Like http://example.net/converturl.php?url=https://example.com/text1/tekst2/123456789 and redirect it to https://example.com/anothertext/123456789 ?

Thanks.